# Does the function $y(x)$ increasing /decreasing?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Given two decreasing functions $H(y), B(y)$, 
And the implicit function $y(x)$:

$3H(y)-4y^3+x^5+1=-B(y)-e^{5x+1}$.

What can I say about the function $y(x)$ in terms of increasing /decreasing?

I know that it's an odd polynomial, but I can't see how it has to do anything about increasing /decreasing.

Thank you.

Comment: $-B(y)-3H(y)+4y^3$ is increasing, right?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin yes but that's just a part of  $y(x)$

Comment: I am trying to help you, Deb., but I just cannot see what do you think that I am doing wrong.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin - I think your example for decreasing isn't correct. Because the derivative turn out to be positive, but I really don't know how to disprove your example.. I'll try to think about it more.

Comment: @Deb.U But you just have to plug in $B(y)=H(y)=2y^3$ in the equation and you will obtain an explicit expression for your $y$ as a function of $x$ (which maybe isnt always possible if dependence is not straightforward), and it will decrease. Where is the problem?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin - I agree with you. It's strange. I'll think about it more.

Comment: @Deb.U Just tell me everything what is not clear to you.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin - your examples are clear, but they are examples not proof so maybe something went wrong. But I can't see the flaw. I'm telling that because if you do implicit derivative for $y$, you will get positive sign. That's why one of us is wrong.

Comment: @Deb.U OK, let us continue for a moment, is your $H(y)$ decreasing as a function of $y$ or of $x$ or both?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin - I'm talking about increasing of $y(x)$ by it's derivative not about $H(y)$ which is clearly decreasing by the question.

Comment: @Deb.U $H(y)$ is decreasing as a function of what?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin - I guess of $x$, seems like a composition function.

Comment: @Deb.U It is a composition, you can view it as a function of $y$ and as a function of $x$ because $y$ is a function of $x$. So it is and it is not a composition, depending on how you view it. Do you see where are the issues?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin - but in the end its $x$. Not sure..

Comment: @Deb.U Ok, so what do you want me to do? Do you want that I also take the implicit derivative?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin - $y'=\frac{-5e^{5x+1}-5x^4} {3H'(y)-12y^2+B'(y)} >0$

Comment: @Deb.U How did you obtain that?  What are $B$ and $H$ doing in the denominator of the fraction?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin - because $(B(y)) '=B' (y)* y'$

Comment: Something is terribly wrong, two approaches lead to two different answers.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin - I know. The problem is that I didn't find flaw in the derivative. Also I can't see what's wrong with your example. But this is a proof, so I guess the example should be checked again in some way..

Comment: But you can clearly see that if you plug in $B=H=-y^3$ then we have one behavior, and if you plug $B=H=2y^3$ then we have another behavior. That is also a proof by an example.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin - maybe someone will clearfy that. I can't see what's wrong. Really.

Comment: But you have some doubts in my approach to the problem.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin - yes because as for me the derivative approach is more full and direct. The problem with proof by examples, again - I speak for myself only, is that not always I can figure out what's wrong, if it's wrong..

Comment: But my approach is of a more elementary nature, it does not involve anything about derivatives at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo have that $-4y^3=-B(y)-e^{5x+1}-x^5-1-3H(y)$, so you have $y^3=\frac{1}{4}
 \cdot(B(y)+e^{5x+1}+x^5+1+3H(y))$.

If $B(y)=H(y)=-y^3$ then $y$ is increasing.

If $B(y)=H(y)={2y^3}$ then $y$ is decreasing.

So, both can happen.

Another approach (more general approach):

You have $3H(y)-4y^3+x^5+1=-B(y)-e^{5x+1}$,

so you have $-B(y)-3H(y)+4y^3=x^5+1+e^{5x+1}$

Write $G(y)=-B(y)-3H(y)$ and $f(x)=x^5+1+e^{5x+1}$.

Then $4y^3=f(x)+(-G(y))$, so $y^3$ is a sum of increasing $f$ and decreasing $-G(y)$, so you see that you cannot say anything in this generality about $y(x)$ because you do not know anything about a manner in which $-G(y)$ decreases.

Comment: How can the second case be? $2y^3$ is increasing, but in the question it's say that $B(y), H(y)$ are decreasing functions.

Comment: @Deb.U $2y^3$ is decreasing if $y$ is decreasing.

Comment: sorry still don't get it after all. How did u know or why $B(h)=-y^3$ is a decreasing function? We don't know anything about $y$. Only that $B(h), H(h)$ are decreasing functions. Same question about $B(h) =2y^3$. How did you know to take those examples and that for sure it will decrease?

Comment: I meant $B(y), H(y)$.

Comment: @Deb.U Listen, if I take first example and bring y´s on the left side then on the right side there is only a function of x and we can solve for y explicitly. Also for the second case.

Comment: The problem looks a little bit circular, and the solution also, that is why youre confused.

Comment: I knew how to take them because I see that I should take them.

Comment: @ Antoine de Paladin - well i think you are wrong, because the function B(h)=2y^3 is increasing by it's graph. also if you take the derivative of the implicit  -  the sign is always positive so $y$ must be increasing.  then again, i might be wrong. thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Deb.U That can also be the case, I will go through your task once again, and why do you mention odd polynomial?

Comment: @ Antoine de Paladin - odd because i know that odd polynomial is increasing. maybe it will help.

Comment: @Deb.U I did some edit, take a look now.

Comment: @ Antoine de Paladin - i saw, thanks but it doesn't mean that you can't know, just that this approach didn't work to determine if it's increasing or decreasing. do you have an example so that $y$ will decrease? your first example is wrong because we know that $B(y)=2y^3$ is increasing same as if $f(x)=2x^3$ is increasing so it's not true.

Comment: @Deb.U Are you sure that $B(y)=2y^3$ is increasing? What if $y(x)=-x^3$? Is then $B$ increasing?

Comment: @ Antoine de Paladin - thank you! i will try to figure out way still im getting that $y$ is only increasing. thank you for all of your help.

Comment: @Deb.U Listen, please, we do not know anything about a manner in which our $-G(y)$ decreases, and the way in which it decreases depends on how is it defined and its definition depends on $y=y(x)$. What should I do in order to clarify you things more?

Comment: If I am wrong, then prove that I am.